# alter output of xml serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, controls

web service response passes back an xml file, one element is type Date, its format has timezone info, e.g.

`12-30-2010T10:00:00+1:00`

my class has a field (DateTime) to receive the value, however, it simply change date to local time.

`12-30-2010T10:00:00+1:00`

will be converted to

`12-30-2010T02:00:00` (My local time is CST).

So the original timezone info is lost.
what I want is just the time ignoring timezone info, simply

`12-30-2010T10:00:00`

or for some way I can extract timezone info in the response, so I can adjust converted time back to original time before conversion.

Anyone know how to do this in C#?

thanks

Comment: How are you deserializing the xml into an instance of your class?  Are you using `XmlSerializer`?

Comment: Yes, I am using xmlSerializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTimeOffset` is like `DateTime` but also preserves the original timezone offset information.  Unfortunately, `XmlSerializer` does not support `DateTimeOffset` (`DataContractSerializer` does, but it will not serialize it to the string you expect).

If you have the option too, I'd recommend you use the `DateTimeOffset` type and an additional `string` property for serialization.  Here's an example:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    const string TimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'sszzz";

    [XmlElement("Time")]
    public string TimeString { get{return Time.ToString(TimeFormat);} set{Time = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(value, TimeFormat, null);} }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTimeOffset Time { get; set; }
}
```

Your code would interact with the `Time` property while `XmlSerializer` will effectively use the `TimeString` property in its place.  You can then precisely control how the conversion to/from xml is handled.

If you don't want to use the `DateTimeOffset` type, you could modify the `TimeString` methods to do something else (i.e. store the time in one field and the offset in another field).